# How to un-elevate permissions in windows with python

Tags: python, permissions, windows-10

I'm trying to run commands as a particular user rather than an administrator.... seems strange, but roll with me here.

I am running my python script as an administrator, but would like to perform certain functions of the script as an underprivileged user.

For example, something like this would be what I would want to accomplish

```
from shutil import copyfile

as_user('testuser', 'P@$$w0rd1', copyfile(src, dst))
```

Other parts of the script would proceed to run as administrator. I've tried using run-as and psexec without any luck as the just end up popping open a new window entirely :|

Other than this, I have no idea how to accomplish this task on windows, with linux this sort of stuff is easy.

Comment: You probably need the Windows APIs for impersonation.  See https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch07s14.html  There are others, Google "python windows impersonation".  Other search engines are available.

Comment: This sounds like what I need, thanks!